# how to change 3 concatenated strings to bytes in python?

Tags: serial-port, pyserial

I am getting an error when running the following code in python 3, I look all over but could not find a right way to do it. any help will be appreciated.

raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'relay read 7\n\r'

I need to send the following string via serial port: relay read #of relay.

```
import sys
import serial

if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print ("Usage: relayread.py <PORT> <RELAYNUM>\nEg: relayread.py COM1 0")
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    portName = sys.argv[1];
    relayNum = sys.argv[2];

#Open port for communication    
serPort = serial.Serial(portName, 19200, timeout=1)

if (int(relayNum) < 10):
    relayIndex = str(relayNum)
else:
    relayIndex = chr(55 + int(relayNum))

serPort.write("relay read "+ relayIndex + "\n\r")

response = serPort.read(25)

if(response.find("on") > 0):
    print ("Relay " + str(relayNum) +" is ON")

elif(response.find("off") > 0):
    print ("Relay " + str(relayNum) +" is OFF")

#Close the port
serPort.close()
```

Comment: I tried  serPort.write(b'relay read '+ b'relayIndex' + b'\n\r') but did not work. also tried  serPort.write(b'["relay read" "relayIndex" "\n\r"]) also failed.

Comment: convert unicode strings to bytes with `encode()`, eg `("a"+chr(55)).encode("utf8")`

Answer (score 0):

Use the string's `encode` method to construct the corresponding byte sequence.

In this case all of the characters in the string are in the ASCII range so it doesn't really matter which encoding scheme you use.  (Differences between encoding schemes generally only matter when you're dealing with non-ASCII characters, ones whose `ord()` value is greater than 127.)  So in this case you don't even need to specify a particular encoding scheme, you can simply use the `encode` method with no argument and let Python apply the platform's default encoding.

To do that, change this:

```py
serPort.write("relay read "+ relayIndex + "\n\r")
```

to this:

```py
serPort.write(("relay read "+ relayIndex + "\n\r").encode())
```

You'll probably have to do the reverse operation to get a string from the byte sequence returned by `serPort.read`.  Change this:

```py
response = serPort.read(25)
```

to:

```py
response = serPort.read(25).decode()
```

BTW, it's typical for line endings in transmitted data to be represented by a Carriage Return followed by a Line Feed, or `"\r\n"`.  In your `serPort.write` call you're using the reverse of that, `"\n\r"`.  That's unusual but if that's what your device needs then so be it.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! I run again adding .encode() and works just fine! really appreciate your time. Thanks.